# Cannot render this line of jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to render the page demonstrated at [this page](http://www.pdavis.nl/ShowSet3.php?Set=1) in PHP, but have a problem with a line like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'click', function() {
    $('#photo').html('<img src="http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_4631.jpg"></img>');
});
```

The following doesn't work:

```
echo "google.maps.event.addListener(marker " . $i . ", 'click', function() {
     $('#photo').html('<img src=\"http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_8302.jpg\"></img>');
 });";
```

What am I doing wrong (I thought that just excaping the two double quotes was required)

Comment: Have you got any JS error in your console ? We don't have enough informations to answer ...

Comment: Try that, there is a problem with $ symbol : `echo 'google.maps.event.addListener(marker'.$i.', "click", function(){$("#photo").html("<img src="http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_8302.jpg"></img>");});';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet answer is:

```
echo "google.maps.event.addListener(marker".$i.", 'click', function() {\n\$('#photo').html('<img src=\"http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_8302.jpg\"></img>');\n});";
```

Using \n to make the indent (for your desired output look) and a \ at the $ to escape it as to stopp PHP from seeing an undefined variable. I also brought your ".$i." together and placed it directly after "marker" as you state the code should look like marker0 marker1 marker2.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a type-o.

I'm thinking the issue is with the space between `marker` and `" . $i . "` ...

Change:

```
echo "google.maps.event.addListener(marker " . $i . ", 'click', function() {
     $('#photo').html('<img src=\"http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_8302.jpg\"></img>');
 });";
```

to  ...

```
echo "google.maps.event.addListener(marker" . $i . ", 'click', function() {
     $('#photo').html('<img src=\"http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_8302.jpg\"></img>');
 });";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the reason you have a syntax error in there is because PHP sees the `{$` and expects that to mean that there will be an embedded variable in the string.

PHP is looking for something like this `echo "... {$varName} ...";`

The syntax you've given it with `{$(...` is confusing it.

You can get around this immediately by escaping the dollar sign with a backslash.

However, since you aren't embedding any variables in the string (even your `$i` is concatenated rather than embedded), you should probably be using sigle quotes rather than double quotes. This would have avoided the issue with the dollar sign altogether (although you would of course have had to escape the single quotes in the string).

Finally, the best advice I can give you is to try to stop generating so much JavaScript code inside your PHP.

You would be far better off putting the code above into a Javascript function, and then generating a function call in your PHP code. For example:

In your JS code you'd have this:

```
function myMapPointer(markerID) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerID, 'click', function(){$('#photo').html('<img src="http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_4631.jpg"></img>');});
}
```

and then your PHP code could look like this:

```
echo "    myMapPointer(marker{$i});\n";
```

Which I'm sure you'll agree is easier to read on both counts.

Comment: It's worth nothing that after you edited the question to put the `{` and `$` on separate lines, the original code no longer has a PHP syntax error in it so the first part of my answer no longer applies. However I stick with my advice to move as much of your JS as possible out of your PHP code for readability and maintainability reasons.

Comment: Thank you for this. simple reason is: I'm reasonably familiar with PHP, but a neophyte in JavaScript; didn't think of doing the JavaScript outside of PHP.

Comment: Upon reflection: Thank you, but I have to generate the JavaScript in PHP because the hard link to a .JPG will be replaced by a different link for each marker, to be pulled out of the database

Comment: By starting again from scratch, I have now totally separated PHP from JavaScript. Indeen a lot more elegant, especially since there is still quite a bit of JavaScript to be added.

Comment: @PeterBeresford - Brilliant. Good descision  :-). Best of luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to embed other code in PHP in my opinion is by using single quotations marks.

Just switch around the single quotation marks in your jQuery to double quotation marks.

Ofcourse in the `img` tag you will need both single and double marks. In this case since we started our echo with a single quotation mark use single quotation marks for the `src` attribute and escape these.

```
echo 'google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, "click", function() {
    $("#photo").html("<img src=\'http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/IMG_4631.jpg\'></img>");
});'
```

With single quotation marks PHP won't try to interpolate code so you will echo literally what you place here.